# Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetch_assoc() in php

Tags: php, function, mysqli, undefined

I am getting an error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetch_assoc()". Can you please advise on how I should proceed?

The code is mentioned below

```
$servername = "localhost";

$username = "s";

$password = "j";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = "select idnew_table, new_tablecol from new_schema.new_table;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$r = count($result);


if ($result['num_rows'] != 10) {


    while($row = $result[fetch_assoc()]){
        echo "id: " . $row["idnew_table"]. " - Name: " .             $row["new_tablecol"];
        }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Try `mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()`.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

`while($row = $result[fetch_assoc()]){`

should be:

`while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){`